# How to make a Onclick Full Page Script not work on certain Function in PHP

Tags: javascript, php

I was given a onclick Fullpage Popup Ad code

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//dolohen.com/apu.php?zoneid=2458038"></script>
```

It works on the whole page and when someone clicks on any part, it opens up a popup.

Now, I don't Want it to work on the Button, cause when someone clicks it, instead of opening the youtube URL, he goes to dolohen link and has to re-click the button to go to youtube URL!

**My problem is I don't want this to work on  this function:**

```
function buttonOnClick()

    {

      window.open('https://www.youtube.com/channel/".$channelID."?sub_confirmation=1', '_blank');

      setTimeout(aTagChange, 3000);

    }


<button onclick="buttonOnClick();" onmouseover="mouseOver();" onmouseout="mouseOut();">Subscribe <i id="ytb" class="fa fa-youtube-square ytb"></i></button>
```

Comment: The problem description is not clear. Please edit it and also tell us what is the current problem & what you want to do

Comment: @brk please check now

Comment: Why can't you remove the `onclick` handle from the button?

Comment: @brk,i don't Want it to work on the Button, cause when someone click it , instead of opening the youtube url , he goes to dolohen link and has to re click the button to go to youtube url !

Comment: That is what I asked , what dont you remove `onclick="buttonOnClick()` from the button

Comment: @brk i want user to go to youtube url bro , not dolohen link

Comment: Conditionally add it, depending on the page... ie: `echo <button...`

Comment: @MiroslavGlamuzina bro can u please send me the code , iam new to this